# Background worker For Loop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

Ok I am a bit new to coding and using the backgroundworker so don't judge me too hard.

Basically i am spawning a bunch of background workers and having them do a task.  The problem is each background worker is doing the same task.  I would like all the spawned background workers to each work on a different task and ignore the task if another background worker has alreday done it.

here is my background worker do work sub:

```
    Private Sub bgw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Dim bgw As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim url As String
    Dim pr As Integer
    Dim prproxy As Integer
    Dim randomLine As Integer

    For rowIndex = 0 To DataGridViewX1.RowCount - 1

        DataGridViewX1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Status").Value = "Working"
        url = DataGridViewX1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("url").Value.ToString



        If SwitchButton1.Value = True Then 'check page rank if proxies are enabled.
            randomLine = RandomNumbers.Next(proxies.TextBoxX1.Lines.Length)
            Dim s As String = proxies.TextBoxX1.Lines(randomLine)
            RandomProxy = Split(s, ":", , CompareMethod.Text)
            pr = PageRank.GooglePageRank.GetPageRankWithProxy(url, RandomProxy(0), RandomProxy(1))
            DataGridViewX1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("proxy").Value = RandomProxy(0) & ":" & RandomProxy(1)
        Else
            pr = PageRank.GooglePageRank.GetPageRank(url) 'If proxies are not enabled do this.
        End If

        DataGridViewX1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("PR").Value = pr
        DataGridViewX1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Status").Value = "Done"


    Next

End Sub
```

I'm guessing my problem is in the for loop, but I can't rap my brain around how to do this without it and make each background worker work on a different URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem you're describing has to do with synchronization - a common problem when progrmming multi-threaded applications.

One solution in your case would be to create a queue of tasks to fulfill and have each background worker work on that queue. When a background worker gets a work entry from the queue, it would be removed so there would not be a change of another background worker doing the same thing.

In your case you seem to  have a list of URLs which you want to work on. Add these URLs to a queue. The background workers would have a `while` loop fetching the next entry from the queue until there is no entry left.

The following is C# pseudo-code (I don't speak much VB.NET), but you'll get the picture:

```
private Queue<string> workerURLs = new Queue<string>();  // this would be a member of the class
private object workerURLsLock = "LOCK"; // This is also a member of the class
```

Then, add the URLs from your grid to the queue, locked

```
lock (workerURLsLock)
    for (...)
        workerURLs.Enqueue(...);
```

After that, start the workers. In the background worker's code, do this:

```
bool workToDo = true;
while (workToDo)
{
    string nextUrl = "";
    lock (workerURLsLock) // IMPORTANT!! LET NO OTHER THREAD MODIFY THE QUEUE
    {
        nextUrl = workerURLs.Dequeue();
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(nextUrl))
    {
        // Do the work
    }
    else
    {
        workToDo = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks that helps alot. My problem now is im not sure how to pass the gridview row that the background worker is working on, for it to be able to insert data back in to the grid, for example: DataGridViewX1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Status").Value = "Working" I will keep tweaking with it, but if you had any insight into that, that would be awesome.

Comment: Of course you can not only add a string to the `Dictionary`, but also objects. You could create a small helper class that has a member for the URL and a member of type `DataGridViewRow`. Then the worker would have both. Depending on the framework version, you could also use `Tuple<string, DataGridViewRow>`. Please do note, however, that accessing the `DataGridViewRow` (i.e. changing their values) in a cross-thread-operation may cause errors. Use `this.Invoke` to make sure such updates are performed in the GUI thread.

Comment: THanks for all your help.  I ended up adding the indexes to a list in the same loop as i added the urls to the synchlocked queue, all UI updates are done in the bgw_ProgressChanged event by passing the indexes as an argument (which from reading is the proper way to do it to my understanding.)  Everything seems to work great.